# CoreData: lightweight migration and iCloud

Tags: core-data, migration, icloud

After a few weeks of integration my CoreData app with iCloud it started working well enough. I mean data are syncing between devices. But then I added a new version of model, and after that the app cannot add iCloud store to coordinator. Method addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error: always returns

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file upload timed out."

And log looks like:

> -PFUbiquitySafeSaveFile waitForFileToUpload:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  (0) ...

Sure, I add iCloud store to coordinator with lightweight migration's options:

```
NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
```

After I rollback the app to previous version of CoreData's model - everything is working again.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?
Thank you in advance for participation.

Comment: Today I've gotten different result - error isn't raising anymore. But who guarantee this won't reproduce on production.

Comment: How does your new model differ from the old one? What changed?

Comment: Only one string attribute was added to the abstract entity. As I mentioned in my comment, I wasn't able to reproduce this problem again.